# Inserting multiple sets of data for a single index value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have a dataframe which is of the following structure:

```
   A B C
0  1 1 0
1  2 2 1
2  3 3 2
3  4 4 3
```

The index and column C are both set to have the same value. This is because I have created a dataframe which uses dates as it's index to cover every day in the year and I have a large collection of data whose dates are deposited in column C. In practice I can deposit as much data as possible and this can cover the majority of the year but there will be some days where there is no data and my dataframe is structed this way to account for it.

What I wish to do is enable support for multiple readings on one day. Currently my program selects which row to put data into by matching the raw data's date with the date in the index column so if I had the following:

```
A B C
2 3 2
```

The row would be selected by the value in column C and inserted into the data frame like so:

```
   A B C
0  1 1 0
1  2 2 1
2  2 3 2
3  4 4 3
```

How would I handle the case where I have two sets of readings on one day whilst keeping the indexing the same and inserting the data based on the column c value.

Like so:

```
A B C
4 3 1
2 4 1
```

And I want to be able to have the following:

```
   A B C
0  1 1 0
1  4 3 1
1  2 4 1
2  2 3 2
3  4 4 3
```

I wish to keep the indexing the same so that the structure of the dataframe is kept the same in covering all days of the year and days where there is multiple days the data can be inserted whilst keeping the index value the same.

Comment: cd123 - let us know if my solution works for you

Comment: Unfortunately whilst this solution is useful I didn't work for what I needed. It's partly my fault for not specifying that the dataframe in my post is a simplified version of what I have. Otherwise I have obtained what I wanted by taking a radically different approach by insert the elements I want to append into a list and appending the list when needed to the frame and sorting after. Thank you for your input anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

**Setup:**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

a = io.StringIO(u'''
A B C
1 1 0
2 2 1
3 3 2
4 4 3
''')

df = pd.read_csv(a, delim_whitespace = True)

b = io.StringIO(u'''
A B C
4 3 1
2 4 1
''')

dfX = pd.read_csv(b, delim_whitespace = True)
```

**Processing:**

```
df = df.loc[~df['C'].isin(dfX['C'])]
df = df.append(dfX).sort_values(by = 'C')
df.index = df['C'].values
```

**Output:**

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  0
1  4  3  1
1  2  4  1
2  3  3  2
3  4  4  3
```